# How to add a function with parameter in addTarget of UIButton in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am a newbie in swift. I have a problem with UIButton. I have a function with parameters which I want to call by the `addTarget` method of a `UIButton`. When I am going to add this function on `addTarget` it gives me the following error-
**Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**

I am also sharing my code part for reference. Please help me with this

```
//button initialization
let MainSkipButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
MainSkipButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50 , y: 48, width: 47.0, height: 24.0)
MainSkipButton.backgroundColor = .blue
MainSkipButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
MainSkipButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
MainSkipButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
MainSkipButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Skip", comment: "Button"), for: .normal)
MainSkipButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
MainSkipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionSkip(sender: UIButton, name: String)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(MainSkipButton)

//function initialization
 @objc func buttonActionSkip(sender: UIButton, name: String) {
        print("Receive parameter string is\(name)")
        sender.isHidden = true
    }
```

Comment: why you need name parameter I confused there ?

Comment: What string do you think your function would receive?

Comment: @sekoyaz: name is a string variable which has the name of the function in string format from which the button is created, I need this name in buttonActionSkip function for getting the reference which button is pressed.

Comment: @PhillipMills: It's just a simple string that has the name of the function in which the button is crested and required in a function in which button action is called.

Comment: anyway you shouldn't use first letter capitalized for instances.
MainSkipButton for types mainSkipButton for instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to pass custom parameters to a `#selector`, as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html),

> Action methods must have a conventional signature. The UIKit framework permits some variation of signature, but both platforms accept action methods with a signature similar to the following:

meaning you method can at least have one of the following signatures:

```
@objc func buttonActionSkip(sender: UIButton)
@objc func buttonActionSkip(sender: UIButton, for event: UIEvent)
```

You can however, change the sender type. A possible solution for your problem could be extending the UIButton class adding a `name` property:

```
class MyMainSkipButton: UIButton {
    var name: String = ""
}
```

Then on your code:

```
//button initialization
let MainSkipButton = MyMainSkipButton(type: .custom)
MainSkipButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50 , y: 48, width: 47.0, height: 24.0)
MainSkipButton.backgroundColor = .blue
MainSkipButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
MainSkipButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
MainSkipButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
MainSkipButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Skip", comment: "Button"), for: .normal)
MainSkipButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
MainSkipButton.name = "what ever the name is"
MainSkipButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionSkip(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(MainSkipButton)


//function initialization
 @objc func buttonActionSkip(sender: MyMainSkipButton) {
    print("Receive parameter string is\(sender.name)")
    sender.isHidden = true
 }
```